# Aerospike Select Limit Java Client

Tags: aerospike

How can I limit the records using java client in Aerospike. It simply scan all records. I want to limit the query only one and then fetch the next one.

Answer (score 0):

Scans can only limit records by percent.

```
ScanPolicy policy = new ScanPolicy();
policy.scanPercent = 1;

client.scanAll(policy, ns, set, myCallback);
```